# jQuery set Ajax Autorefresh on window.onload function

Tags: javascript

I have praytimes function using javascript.

```
window.onload=function()
    {
        jadwal_sholat = function()
        {
            geo = [1.03000000, 103.92000000, 3.07];
            timezone = +7;

            prayTimes.tune( {imsak: 2, subuh: 2, dhuhur: 2, ashar: 2, maghrib: 2, isya: 2} );

            var date = new Date(); // today
            prayTimes.setMethod('Depag');
            var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, geo, timezone);
            var list = ["Imsak", "Subuh", "Dhuhur", "Ashar", "Maghrib", "Isya"];
            var thisday=date.getDay();
            var thismonth=date.getMonth();
            var thisdate=date.getDate();
            var thisyear=date.getFullYear();
            var thisminute = date.getMinutes();
            thisminute = ("0" + thisminute).slice(-2);
            var thishour = date.getHours();
            thishour = ("0" + thishour).slice(-2);
            var thisseconds = date.getSeconds();
            thisseconds = ("0" + thisseconds).slice(-2);
            var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Agu", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Des");
            var name_of_days = new Array("Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jum"+"'"+"at", "Sabtu");
            var day_name = name_of_days[thisday];
            var monthname = months[thismonth];
            var tanggal = thishour+': '+ thisminute+': ' +thisseconds+', '+day_name+", "+thisdate+" "+monthname+" "+thisyear;
            var currentTimeF = thishour+':'+ thisminute;

            var html = '<table>';
            for(var i in list)
            {
                html += '<td class="box '+ list[i]+'">'+ list[i]+'<div class="timeValue">'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+'</div></td>';

                if(currentTimeF+":00" == times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+":00")
                {
                }
            }
            html += '</table>';
            document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

            dateNow = day_name+", "+thisdate+" "+monthname+" "+thisyear;
            currentTime = thishour+':'+ thisminute+':'+thisseconds;
            document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = dateNow;
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = currentTime;
        }

        show = function() {
            jadwal_sholat();
        }

        show();
        loadTime = function(){
            jadwal_sholat();
            setTimeout(loadTime, 1)
        }
        loadTime();
    }
```

The function is running OK.

But now I want some value getting from database.

geo and timezone <-- will get from database.

And I do not want to refresh the page, so it will be auto refresh using ajax maybe?

What I think is:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "chkValue",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
        mosqueeID: ID
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
        var timezone = jsonStr.timezone;
    }
});
```

How to do that? Is it possible?

Comment: how is your onload function and ajax request connected?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, how to do that? :)

Comment: I meant to ask, where are you exactly using the `timezone` returned from the ajax request

Comment: first the ajax will running every 1 second and load the data from database then set to timezone = jsonStr.timezone; inside jadwal_sholat = function()

Comment: wrap your ajax request inside a function and call that function using `setInterval` so that it loads for every second and extracts the timezone from the database

Comment: Do you have the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function loadAjax(){
$.ajax(
{
    url: "chkValue",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
        mosqueeID: ID
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
        //return this timezone or use this outside of the function with global scope
        var timezone = jsonStr.timezone;
    }
});
}

//reload every 1 second
setInterval(loadAjax(), 1000);
```

Try this out and let me know if it doesnt work. You may have to include all your function within the `success` of the ajax request

Comment: How to set that timezone inside jadwal_sholat = function() ?

Comment: move that `jadwal_sholat` to inside of the ajax success function

Comment: Not working sir, got error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error in jQuery

Comment: have you included the jquery library as an `src` ?

Comment: I have added the library but it's not load every second. Only 1 time load

Comment: remove your onload function and have just this ajax request . That should resolve the problem